# Purge script with mutltiple conditions

Tags: python, file, purge

I'm writing yet another python purge script.  This is replacing a very old bash script with tons of find -delete which take up to 9h to purge our video backend.

I know there is tons of those either on stack or right in google but thing is i have a few more constraints which left me to write what i find poor/unefficient code.

consider the following dir structure:

> /data/channel1/video_800/0001/somefile_800_001.ts
> /data/channel1/video_800/0001/somefile_800_002.ts
> /data/channel1/video_800/0002/somediffile_800_001.ts
> /data/channel1/video_800/0002/somediffile_800_002.ts
> /data/channel1/video_800.m3u8
> /data/channel1/video_900/0001/someotherfile_900_001.ts
> /data/channel1/video_900/0002/afile_900_001.ts
> /data/channel1/video_900/0003/bfile_900_001.ts
> /data/channel1/video_900/0003/cfile_900_001.ts
> /data/channel1/video_900.m3u8
>
> /data/channel2/video_800/0001/againsomefile_800_001.ts
> /data/channel2/video_800/0001/againsomefile_800_001.ts
> /data/channel2/video_800.m3u8
>
> /data/sport_channel/video_1000/0001/somefile.ts
> /data/sport_channel/video_1000/0001/somefile2.ts

First thing that interests me is the channel name since there is a rule for channel* and one for sport*.

Second thing is the end of the video dirs that equals the bitrate... 800, 900, 1000 since these can have different retention days.

Finaly i'm going through everything and remove files based on bitrate and extention.

The bellow code works but is overly complicated and i'm sure not very pythonic.  Since what i care most in this case is performance i'm sure there is a more efficient way to do this.  Stacking for loop in for loop is not only poor design but also gets me a **'find_files' is too complex [mccabe]** in my pymode.

** Left the remove function out of the code example but it's just a plain try:except using os.rmdir and os.remove

I'm open to all suggestions to improving my code.

Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import time
import fnmatch

path = '/data'
debits_short = ['200', '700', '1000', '1300', '2500']
debits_long = ['400', '1800']

def find_files(chan_name, debits, duration):

    time_in_secs = time.time() - (duration * 24 * 60 * 60)

    # List channel
    for channel in os.listdir(path):

        # Match category channels
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(channel, chan_name):

            # Go through bitrates
            for debit in debits:

                # Channel path now the default search path
                channel_path = path + channel

                # Walk through channel path to match bitrate files
                for root, dirs, files in os.walk(channel_path, topdown=False):
                    for filename in files:

                        # Remove files that contain _bitrate_ and end with ts
                        if '_' + debit + '_' in filename:
                            if filename.endswith('.ts'):
                                if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(root, filename)):
                                    if os.stat(os.path.join(root, filename)).st_mtime <= time_in_secs:
                                        remove(os.path.join(root, filename))

                        # Remove playlist files that contain bitrate.m3u8
                        if filename.endswith(debit + '.m3u8'):
                            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(root, filename)):
                                if os.stat(os.path.join(root, filename)).st_mtime <= time_in_secs:
                                    remove(os.path.join(root, filename))

                    # Remove empty dirs
                    for dir in dirs:
                        if not os.listdir(os.path.join(root, dir)):
                            remove(os.path.join(root, dir))


find_files('channel*', debits_long, 3)
find_files('sport*', debits_short, 7)
```

Comment: First though:  [Flat is better than nested.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible approach:

```
import os
import glob
import time


class Purge(object):

    removable_extensions = ['ts', 'm3u8']

    def __init__(self, basedir, channel_pattern, debits,
                 older_than_days, test_mode=False):
        self.basedir = basedir
        self.channel_pattern = channel_pattern
        self.debits = debits
        self.older_than_secs = time.time() - 24*60*60*older_than_days
        self.test_mode = test_mode  # If `True`, do not delete files.

    def delete_file(self, filepath):
        try:
            os.remove(filepath)
        except OSError:
            pass

    def file_for_deletion(self, filepath):
        # Return `True` if a file meets all conditions for deletion.
        filename, ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filepath))
        condition_ext = ext[1:] in self.removable_extensions
        condition_old = os.stat(filepath).st_mtime <= self.older_than_secs
        condition_deb = any(
            '_{}_'.format(d) in filename or filename.endswith(d)
            for d in self.debits
            )
        return all((condition_ext, condition_old, condition_deb))

    def purge_channel(self, channel_dir):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(channel_dir):
            for name in files:
                filepath = os.path.join(root, name)
                if self.file_for_deletion(filepath):
                    print filepath
                    if not self.test_mode:
                        self.delete_file(filepath)
            #TODO: delete empty directories here.

    def purge(self):
        channels = glob.glob(os.path.join(self.basedir, self.channel_pattern))
        for channel_dir in channels:
            self.purge_channel(channel_dir)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    purge_job_info = dict(
        basedir=r'path/to/data',  # All channel folders live here.
        channel_pattern='channel*',  # `glob` pattern.
        debits=['400', '1800'],
        older_than_days=7,
        )

    p = Purge(**purge_job_info)
    p.test_mode = True
    p.purge()
```

Comment: I've tought about using a class at first but i'm not that experienced in python to write it on my own but i'll be decrypting this with alot of attention first chance i get... looks pretty good.  If i need more "channels" or bit rate i just need to instanciate the class with different job_info?  Mucho thanks!

Comment: Added the delete_dir function plus other jobs and it's blazzing fast!!!  I'll try to replicate the module approach every time for my other scripts.  It's simple yet so efficiant.  That is why i love python (even if i'm still very much learning).  Thanks again!